# Google Cloud TPU -- no TPU being used

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am trying to run a simple program on TPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
print("Device:", tpu.master())
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)

a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

with strategy.scope():
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
    print("c device: ", c.device)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    print(c.eval())
```

When I run this, it looks like the TPU is being found. However, none of the logged devices have 'TPU' in the name -- it is all on the CPU.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide more context about  how you're running this code? I also suggest you to take a look in the [Cloud TPU Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tpu) where is explained how to run a model  using TPUs

Comment: it turns out that I was trying to do the impossible! According to the docs, the tf.Estimator API is the only way to run TF1.1X code on TPU.

Answer (score 2):

`strategy.scope()` is for model training.

If you want to run `tf.matmul` on a TPU you could use either this:

```
with tf.device('/TPU:0'):
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

Or

```
@tf.function
def matmul_fn(x, y):
  z = tf.matmul(x, y)
  return z

z = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))
print(z)
```

Details are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu).